# LuaSocket (UDP) not receiving datagrams

Tags: lua, udp, datagram, luasocket

I'm experimenting with LuaSocket for a project I'm working on. I've chosen UDP as my protocol.

Looking for docs and tutorials online, I've attempted to create a client-server pair for testing and learning.

According to what I've read, the following code should work. However, only the server seems to be working properly. The client sends a message, but it will not receive the reply from the server.

Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

Server:

```
-- Server
#!/usr/bin/env lua5.1

local socket = require("socket")

udp = socket.udp()
udp:setsockname("*", 53474)
udp:settimeout(0)

while true do
    data, ip, port = udp:receivefrom()
    if data then
        print("Received: ", data, ip, port)
        udp:sendto(data, ip, port)
    end
    socket.sleep(0.01)
end
```

Client:

```
-- Client
#!/usr/bin/env lua5.1

local socket = require("socket")

udp = socket.udp()
udp:setpeername("127.0.0.1", 53474)
udp:settimeout(0)

udp:send("Data!")
data = udp:receive()
if data then
    print("Received: ", data)
end
```

Comment: remove or increase timeout in client. It works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timeout value you set is `0`, which causes the client timeout every time.

To fix it, give it a positive timeout value:

```
udp:settimeout(1)
```

Or set it to `nil` or a negative value, so it blocks indefinitely:

```
udp:settimeout()
```

or

```
udp:settimeout(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Such an obvious solution, but something I completely overlooked!