# lua udp not working between computers

Tags: lua, udp, ethernet

my udp code doesn't work when sending from computer 1 to computer 2, but it works sending from comp 2 to comp 1. I have tried both on the same computer, works fine as expected. The computers are connected through ethernet on a lan, and windows picks up the computers and lets me log in and read/write to/from the computers.
Server:

```
local socket = require "socket"

-- begin
local udp = socket.udp()
udp:settimeout(1)
udp:setsockname('*', 12345)
local data, msg_or_ip, port_or_nil
local cmd, parms
local running = true
print "Beginning server loop."
while running do
    data, msg_or_ip, port_or_nil = udp:receivefrom()
    if data then
        print(data,msg_or_ip,port_or_nil)
        udp:sendto(data,msg_or_ip,port_or_nil)
    elseif msg_or_ip ~= 'timeout' then
        print("Unknown network error: "..tostring(msg))
    end

    socket.sleep(0.01)
end
```

Client:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local address, port = "192.168.137.161", 12345
udp = socket.udp()
udp:settimeout(1)
while true do
    udp:setpeername(address, port)
    udp:send(io.read())
    udp:close()
    --udp:setsockname("*",12345)
    data, msg_or_ip, port_or_nil = udp:receivefrom()
    print(data, msg_or_ip, port_or_nil)
    udp:close()
end
```

The client sends the message, server picks it up, and should echo it right back, but the client spits out
    `nil    refused nil`, with the tab between nil and refused.
I think this is mostly just something with sending from the server computer to the client computer, since it should just echo the data.

I could see how this problem would be hard to answer, due to not everyone having full access to two computers at once. For the record lua 5.1 is used on both, socket is v2.0.2 on both as well.

Comment: Check firewall settings on both Windows

Comment: sorry for the late response, I opened up all ports for udp & tcp on both incoming and outgoing, and then my equivalent code in python worked when I opened up its set of ports, so I'll have to try that out

Comment: yeah when I switched the ports to the ones python used, and opened up ports 12345 for UDP/TCP on incoming and outgoing, it didn't say anything. the server picked up nothing and the client thought everything was fine

Comment: Sorry, bad comment removed

Comment: You missed udp:settimeout(), the details are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105571/luasocket-udp-not-receiving-datagrams

Comment: ok after school when I get back to my setup I'l try it out

Comment: so Ive found now that it wasn't the timeout that did it, although that may have been the case, had the main problem not existed. it was the fact that I closed the socket, I can't believe I didn't catch that. now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for all who were wondering, it was because I closed the socket. nothing major.